# How to show image in tooltip data?

Tags: css, hover, tooltip

I found an example tooltip html css which is working exactly I am looking for. but instead of showing text, I would like to show image. here is the link.

[codepen link](https://codepen.io/cbracco/pen/kNMqmJ)

can we show images on data-tooltip or is it limited to text content only? I tried like this, but it did not work.:

```
<a href="#" class="tooltip-top" data-tooltip="<img src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_trulli.jpg">">Tooltip</a>
```

Comment: Have a look at how they use that data attribute. It goes into the content property, so you need to add URL(….)). It is not adding HTML which is what you are giving it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The codepen works with a pseudo element (`::after`) that is shown on hover and uses the text of the `data` attribute of its parent.

<s>It's not possible to show an image inside the content of a pseudo element.</s> It apparently IS possible to have an image inside the content of a pseudo element, but not the way you wrote it. You have a HTML tag inside an attribute of a HTML tag. That's not how HTML works at all. You will need to use the image URL in the CSS of the pseudo element. `content: url(...);` or You could use the image as a `background-image` of the pseudo element, which would require some additional CSS styles for width, height, etc.

OR:

If the image URL is not available to be used in CSS, you will have to build it in a completely different approach where you have e.g. `div` containers with the images built in the HTML, next to each of the links that are only shown when you hover the respective link. You could do that with HTML/CSS only or with JavaScript.

Comment: If I possible to have an image as content in a pseudo element, but it’s not an HTML img element. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content

Comment: okay, learned sth new here. I have adjusted my answer accordingly.

Comment: thank you both of you for taking your time and providing in-depth explanations. much appreciated,